# How to best demonstrate multiple Tridion users?

Tags: cme, authorization

When explaining how Tridion works, I find it helps having two browsers or tabs open to show how separate users interact with the CMS.

I'll typically have say, Chrome and Firefox open with two different users logged in or Chrome and Chrome's Incognito tab open with separate users and sessions.

But I sometimes have a hard time "losing" a user for a given browser. For example, in Chrome, I'll "obliterate" the available items (from the beginning of time) under `Clear browsing data`, close the browser, and re-open the Tridion CME still logged in as the same user. There's no single sign-on in these setups--I log in using the domain\user and password manually.

**How do I get Chrome to "forget" my user?** Any other recommendations on how to test or demonstrate multiple users for scenarios like check in/out or workflow?

**Edit**: I tested and documented Dominic's [multiple url suggestion in this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1197/46), thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility might be to map multiple host headers for your CM site, and of course, also in your hosts file. So then you could log in on one tab of your browser to

```
http://devs.tridion.local
```

and in another tab to

```
http://authors.tridion.local
```

As far as the browser is concerned, these will be separate sites.

Comment: that's an interesting solution dom

Comment: Downside is that you would have to explain to your class what you were doing or they'd get confused. Some people won't know about host header mappings and hosts files... so definitely a question of judging your audience.

Comment: Yes, that's worked on my local VM (and I'm actually using .local as the suffix). I'll see what the team thinks of it, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I often work with Chrome in *Incognito* mode or FF in *Private Browsing* mode. Then it doesn't store the passwords

Comment: chrome also has an option for using multiple identities http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/multi-profiles

Comment: Ok, I found the multiple user option under `chrome://settings` and added a user with its own cool icon (I think the above link is for Chrome with the Chromium OS). Going to localhost with this other user seems to keep the saved password for my admin user, though. :-( I added the "ninja" user to my desktop anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding How do I get Chrome (or Firefox) to "forget" my user?

If you are clearing your browser history and still you are not prompted for the User Login then please check in the "Saved Password" list and see if your CME address is there; if it is, then remove it from there and choose the option of never save password for this website.

If you are using IE, then the steps will be a bit different as you may need to go to Security tab in IE Option and need to choose "prompt for user id and password" in User Authentication settings

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, I found the setting under "Passwords and forms" in Chrome. Thanks, Pankaj.

Comment: Checking again in Chrome I'm not actually seeing the CMS url under `Saved passwords` or `Never saved`. Maybe it's something else in my case (Google account or an extension?). I'll keep looking.

Comment: Quite Strange!! Anyway, tried clearing browser history/cache etc., close the browser, re-open the browser and hit your CMS url, per default behaviour of the browser it should ask you to save the password or never save the password for this site, you may choose the "never save password" for this site. If this option does not come can you re-check for any extension being added to the Chrome (Tools -> Extension) which might be stopping  this behaviour.

Comment: My mistake, I apparently never chose the "never" option. I've selected it and can now see the url in the "never" section. The remaining scenario is why/how Chrome saves passwords when we don't explicitly choose to save the password. :-)

Comment: The remaining scenario: (My very personal thoughts) I think this depends on the SDL Tridion Implementation regarding session. If you are maintaining session and it is not yet expired, any typical browser will let you log-in regardless whether you chose the Save Password or not, now the question is what is the duration of this session before it get expired automatically.

Comment: One more follow-up on this. It seems (at least some versions of?) Chrome uses some of IE's Security Settings. If having issues changing users for Chrome, check IE's User Authentication > Login settings. For example, you can have it prompt for user name and password (independent of the actual saved passwords).