# Tridion VM Multiple Host Headers

Tags: 2011, configuration, content-manager, iis-and-asp.net

I'm following a [suggestion from Dominic Cronin](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1162/46) on setting up multiple host headers to help demonstrating different users on the same CMS, but I'm stuck at the login pop-up.

1. As an administrator, I added the following to: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and saved the changes.

   127.0.0.1   authors.tridion.local
   127.0.0.1   admin.tridion.local
2. In the Site Bindings for SDL Tridion 2011 (my CMS installation) in IIS 7.5, I have:

   **For authors**:

   - Type: http
   - IP address: `All Unssigned` (i.e. "*")
   - Port: 80
   - Host name: authors.tridion.local

   **For admins**:

   - Type: http
   - IP address: `All Unssigned` (i.e. "*")
   - Port: 80
   - Host name: admin.tridion.local

   (tried other ports, but 80 works fine for multiple headers)

When attempting to visit `http://authors.tridion.local` or `http://admin.tridion.local` in Chrome, I'm prompted to log in (so the host and IIS setup seems to be partially working), but entering a valid user name and password won't get me past the login pop-up.

Cancelling the login pop-up gives me the IIS error:

```
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

Additional info:

- Application pool for Site `SDL Tridion 2011` is `SDL Tridion 2011` with physical path set to `C:\Program Files(x86)\Tridion\web`. This application pool is set to .NET v4.0 as `Integrated` for pipeline mode.
- When attempting to log in to one of these additional URLs, my already logged in administrator (on `http://localhost`), will see authorization errors such as `/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetItem failed to execute. STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException`.

I'm thinking I'm missing something with the ports (since updated to separate ports), Windows folder permissions, or an appropriate restart. **How do I set up separate urls for different users on a Tridion CMS instance/VM?**

**Update 1**:

- I disabled `LoopBackChecks` with regedit and restarted the VM (thanks, Chris). I can at least get past the login pop-ups to see most of the CME in Chrome and IE (after changing IE's security level).
- I tried updating the WebRoot's web.config based on [Dominic's post](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/mysterious-404-errors-showing-up-in-the-tridion-message-centre), but changes to `multiport/multihostname` under `appSettings`, `httpModules`, `modules`, and `serviceHostingEnvironment` were *not* needed.

**Update 2** (part of the solution):

By default, for .NET 4.0, [multiple headers for WCF sites in IIS is disabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rampo/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site).

Adding `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"` to `serviceHostingEnvironment` now lets me browse each url as different users.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment
    aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
```

Comment: Was you environment working correctly before adding the hostnames? on say http://localhost? Is it expecting a domain as part of the login?

Comment: Yes, localhost let me log in as the current user (Windows username/password). I was able to provide either the user directly, and I believe `.\username` worked as well to automatically select the domain.

Comment: I'm wondering if a "switch user" GUI extension might be easier to apply across CMS's--I'm only trying this for demos and explanations involving a dev VM and multiple users. It doesn't *have* to be a multihost/port setup. :-D

Comment: That is a good idea - I think the multihost/port approach could cause confusion to less technical editors. I can already hear "Why are there two different Tridion's?" :)

Comment: Why did you change from port 80? You can have multiple sites running on the same port as long as the have different host header mappings.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan... Why are there two different Tridions.. I made a similar comment when I first suggested this approach. For training, it depends a lot on the audience and how well you prime them.

Comment: @DominicCronin aye, the sites with different host header mappings work--I get a "partial" CME load for any of them, all using port 80. But I'm lost on the Web.config service settings (and if any are even needed--I can get one url working at a time by setting `Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo` and `baseAddressPrefixFilters`). I'll update if I can get this working. :-)

Comment: One more note: we can also easily set up "friendly" domain names by using the machine's name as well. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had issues with than in the past. Something to do with LoopBackChecks. I disabled it by following http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Also check out [Installation issue with SDL Tridion 2013 & SDL Web 8 CME not loading all items properly](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/936/installation-issue-with-sdl-tridion-2013-cme-not-loading-all-items-properly)

Comment: Ok, I'm part way there, after disabling LoopBackChecks and restarting, I am able to enter the passwords for the separate urls. I'm still getting `/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings failed to execute. STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException` and the username doesn't show on the `SDL Tridion` tab (i.e. "Welcome, .").  I have Windows Authentication set for the IIS Tridion CMS site like Vivek has in the other TRex question. With Windows Auth, should my logged in user match? I get the error regardless if the user matches.

Comment: Use fiddler to check the full path and credentials supplied to /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings. Sounds like credentials are not making it on the service call

Comment: Looks like it. Fiddler shows a "500" for GetUserSettings when using Chrome, but interestingly IE stops completely with a `401 Unauthorized` (and gets "stuck" at the loading .gif). I'll try a bit more and maybe research this separately or start another question.

Comment: For IE not loading, I didn't have the sites set to trusted or local intranet. I updated the question with more info.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This worked, I was just missing an additional attribute for `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled` set to `true`.