# Content Manager Explorer not loading

Tags: cme, web8.5

I have installed SDL Web 8.5 and while trying to browse the Content Manager Explorer, it does not load it (appears loading). Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion StackExchange site, it would be very beneficial to your question if you would **edit** it and provide some more details about your issue. Please describe it with as many details as possible, keep in mind none of us here can see what you are seeing, nor do we have a crystal ball.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for your response,i have added an screenshot

Comment: Please attach screenshot from chrome console and network tab, above screen shots are irrelevant to your CME problem.

Comment: Hi Raj, i just attached an screenshot of the chrome console

Comment: Please supply more installation detail. Does this CMS have a local database? Is this running on a physical box, VM, AWS, Azure? Did you use the Quick Install Script?

Comment: Please try this [article](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/tridion-2013-cme-not-loading-properly-after-setting-iis-authentication/4727#4727) and activate the WCF services.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen 404 errors being reported by IIS instead of 500 (some sort of security factor from IIS). If you have a 404 on a GET (all I see in your images are POST) can you try calling that URL directly? IIS may then give you more details on the actual cause of the error.

Comment: Hi Nuno, thanks for your answer. During the installation s (.exe) everything looks fine. I see 2 starnge things though. First, discovery service which should be up and running in the services, is not. I tried also as you suggested to open the 404 links in the browser and it doesn´t. , it replies with 404 in the browser, localhost page does not exist!!Could it be a performance issue of the windows server/IIS?

Comment: Tridion is decoupled, discovery doesn't affect the CM back-end. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16gb,server is running in a w7 pc, virtual windows server 16 sp1

Comment: OK, that's double what I normally use... not a memory issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you restarted the machine after SDL Web CM installation? If you have already tried so, could you please provide some more details regarding the error by checking in the `eventviewer -> applications -> Tridion logs`

Update1: Also, Please verify your browser settings are correctly configured to allow popups
[Configuring your Web browser for Content Manager Explorer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33&addHistory=true&query=Configuring%2520your%2520Web%2520browser%2520for%2520Content%2520Manager%2520Explorer&scope=&tid=4ae22d2e-8786-48c2-9e28-d09474700264&filename=GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DConfiguring%2520your%2520Web%2520browser%2520for%2520Content%2520Manager%2520Explorer&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1497959936940&currentQuery=Configuring%2520your%2520Web%2520browser%2520for%2520Content%2520Manager%2520Explorer&currentScope=)

Update2: From your new screenshots, I can see that you are not able to start the discovery service successfully and the reason for that is you have configured the OAuth credentials wrongly in your .
Solution : either update your OAuth user credentials properly [Content Delivery OAuth authentication framework](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-80AD06B5-DB74-4AE8-9934-4BA8BC1C6D51#docid=GUID-81F2D60E-F9A6-4411-A047-B4A09F8733BC&filename=GUID-81F2D60E-F9A6-4411-A047-B4A09F8733BC.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-81F2D60E-F9A6-4411-A047-B4A09F8733BC&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DOAuth%2520Token&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1498151179740&currentQuery=OAuth%2520Token&currentScope=)or disable the OAuth for now following the [Disabling OAuth authentication](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-80AD06B5-DB74-4AE8-9934-4BA8BC1C6D51)(for all microservices, recommended only for testing purposes)

Comment: Hi Rajesh, yes, i did restart the windos server yesterday (VM) after completing the instalation. I´m new into SDL WEB, where can i find the eventviewer?

Comment: in the event viewer of windows apps tridion i just see info entries,

Comment: @Rajesh: In the run window type "eventvwr" command, Go to expand Event Viewer (local) -> Applications and Services Logs -> Tridion

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you still have issues, you might also find some useful info in the Chrome Browser developer tools console regarding the UI issues (like some of the URL will endup in 404 error, 500 error, etc.,)

Comment: how can i attach an screenshot, i see some 404 that might provide some info to you about the problem?

Comment: i have just attached an screenshot at the start of the thread

Comment: Error 404 indicates that some of the functionality is not available , so it looks like a Tridion installation issue. Please repair your installation and give a try again. Check the installation log files for any error logs.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i have attached a new screenshot of the installation, is it normal the warnings?

Comment: Hi Igor, your new screenshot shows problems with the discovery service which is a part of content delivery. I have updated my answer now.As it is not related to Content Manager, I am just wondering whether you were able to solve the problems with CME and move further with content delivery setup?

Comment: Hi Rajesh,the warnings/error with the discovery service appeared always, the instllation of the .exe does not give any problem. I can see that the discovery service is always stopped, and even i restart it, it stops by itself. This is all the information i can provide. Also, none of the ports that give the warnings are up, i mean the 8081, 8083..., so i really have no idea how to move forward

Comment: you can update/disable the OAuth to get it fixed, please see my answer update2 for instructions. However, if you are not able to open CME in browser, fixing the issues with content delivery microservices is not going to help much.

Comment: so the OAuth fix has nothing to do then with the CME what about the 404 errors in the console and the fail to connect to the 8081,8082, 8083 ... ports?

Answer (score -1):

Top left hand corner, there is the settings\flyout button, click on it, you should get a flyout, click on Content Explorer in the flyout. I think you may find the CME show up or a more specific error.