# How to logout from Content Manager Explorer in IE11

Tags: 2013, cme, content-manager

By clearing cookies for the domain, I was able to logout from Tridion CME in Chrome/Firefox...

But not in IE11.. I have cleared the cookies, also deleted the history etc. but still not able to logout from Tridion in IE11.

[image]

Is there any way out to do the same? Also, let me know if we can set the auto logout time to say 240 minutes (4 hours).

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could this be because the Content Management Explorer (CME) site is in the **Intranet** Zone and that Automatic logon is enabled (for that Zone) within the Internet Explorer Security Settings?

[image]

Can you change this to **Prompt for username and password** and then try clearing cookies again?

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: +1. For those that give demos or have taken Tridion training, you might recognize the `Prompt for user name and password` setting to demo workflow and other two-user scenarios. Using incognito mode, multiple browsers, or maybe [multiple host headers](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1198/46) (though not as clear) can help as well when dealing with multiple logins. I'd guess Saurabh would want different users for development, testing, and/or QA.

Comment: Cheers Alvin. Yes, multiple browsers is normally my weapon of choice for Workflow (and similar) demos.

Answer (score 1):

By default Internet Explorer will preserve your temporary internet files, cookies, etc for websites in your favourites: [image: Preserve Favorites website data]

Is this checkbox checked?  If so, if you uncheck it and repeat everything should be cleared.

Comment: This cheeckbox is already checked.. :(

Comment: You need to uncheck it ;-)

Comment: Sorry for reading it incorrectly...
however, I have tried unchecking it.. but no luck in IE11:( :(
in IE9 its working...