# How to Logout from CMS 2013 SP1 in IE 11 and Chrome 38

Tags: 2013, cme, browser

In Chrome and IE browsers, we want to login diff credentials as old credentials are not working and CME is not accessible.
Could anyone please suggest how to logout from these browsers as I already clear the cache but yet not able logout.

I even tried to follow things from below link but not aste the success.

> [How to logout from Content Manager Explorer in IE11](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/how-to-logout-from-content-manager-explorer-in-ie11)

Thanks

Comment: are you using Windows auth in IE?

Comment: Some people use Chrome in "Incognito" mode, so it always prompts for login information.

Comment: http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/5634dae5e4de020c30dd8cdd

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. In chrome,  type "chrome://settings/" in address bar -> there will be an option to manage passwords

[image]

2. Chrome 38->
   Press Ctrl+Shift+Delete -> in the window check passwords -> click clear browsing data

[image]

Comment: These things I alrady did, but still browser not cleared.

Answer (score 1):

What i've found to work well in IE is to switch the website to the "restricted" zone; then go to that website; then switch the website back to the "intranet" or "trusted sites" zone and finally go to the website again; you should once again be prompted for username/password for the site.

Don't forget to close the browser completely between each step!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Go to Internet Options -> Content Tab->AutoComplete ->Settings

- Uncheck "Ask me before saving passwords" to stop IE from prompting for passwords.
- Uncheck "User names and passwords on forms" to prevent IE from saving usernames and passwords, completely

[image]

AND

Clear your password from Control Panel -> Credential Manager. 
Select your Website URL and then **Remove from Vault**

[image]

Comment: Already unchecked the checkboxes, also there is no entry in credential manager.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? Is it Intranet site? and as you mentioned you already checked "prompt for user name and password" in security settings as given in post in your question.

Comment: Windows 2012 version on Azure environment, Yes I tried in both the ways(Checked and Unchecked).

Comment: @nash there are various zones in security setting Intranet, Internet, trusted sites, i hope you are setting prompt option on proper one, also you can try http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Prevent-Internet-Explorer-from-remembering-passwords

Answer (score 0):

When I change my password and so run into this issue, closing **all** browser tabs *and* instances and then restarting the browser always works for me.

Do not just close the browser as you may have it set to re-open the tabs from the last session (which includes the cached authentication). Make sure it starts a completely new instance of the browser. You may even want to verify in Task Manager that there are no instances running after you've closed the browser, before restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

Check which zone the website is and modify that zone, i know it's on the previous link above but this always worked for me, don`t forget it requires a machine reboot

[image: Custom security zone]