# Can I install Tridion 2013 SP1 with multiple Content Manager Servers

Tags: 2013, cme, clustering

I am looking for a document or solution to install and configure the Tridion 2013 SP1 with multiple Content Manager servers. It is kind of a pool of CM servers to service the requests.

Comment: Hi Prashanth and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. What parts are you not sure about? I'll post the documentation reference but add any additional questions or things you've tried to get better answers and feedback from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDL Live Content documentation has scaling information under "[Scaling SDL Tridion](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F61A79C7-C901-463C-A614-5CC938AAA6ED)" ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

Clustering the Content Manager isn't your only option. You could also look into scaling out <strike>the Database,</strike> Search, Workflow, or Publishing (as well as Content Delivery).

**Edit**:
Nick points out you cannot scale out the Content Manager Database. My mistake, I misread the following:

> **Installing database server on a dedicated machine**  Except in a single-machine setup, always install the Content Manager database on a
>   separate machine. Preferably, this should be a machine with at least 2
>   GB of RAM that scales up easily, has multiple processors, and has
>   network access in the Gigabit range. Set the default network protocol
>   of the machine to TCP/IP (if you use SQL Server, use the Client
>   Network Utility to do this).

So you can "scale" the database server *up* rather than *out*. Basically be careful with terms:

- **dedicated**, as something on its own server
- **up** or **upscale**, referring to threads or upgrading a server (RAM, CPU, etc)
- **out** or **outscale**, the multiple servers you were looking for

Comment: Unless this changed since 2011sp1, you can't scale out the CM DB. It's not supported. The only thing supported is an active/passive configuration, meaning that the additional DB server acts as a backup in case the primary goes down.

Comment: Thank you very much Alvin. Yes, you are right, Clustering the Content Manager is not only the option. I was looking for the documentation to start with. For sure, I will be back with more number of queries.

Comment: You're right, Nick, on the dedicated DB. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Alvin says, you can scale out to multiple Content Manager servers (with a load balancer to manage the traffic to each).

As well as being able to spread the load and provide fault tolerance, scaling out the Content Manager and accessing the CME site through a load balancer allows you to easily put a 'holding page' in place (for the CME interface), if needed.

A holding page can be especially useful during deployments between environments, when you may not want editors to be editing or publishing content. (The administrators doing the deployment can have direct access to one of the Content Manager servers.)

If you do this, and scale out the Content Manager servers, then there are a few things that you will need to look out for:

1. You will need to ensure that the Content Manager Search is configured correctly - implementing a Master and a Slave setup.
2. As the Tridion Content Management Explorer interface is likely to be accessed on a number of URLs (the load balanced one and a direct one (for each server)), you will need to ensure that [multiple host headers](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/tridion-vm-multiple-host-headers) are configured properly.
3. You will probably need to implement 'sticky sessions' on the load balancer.

Comment: Thank you Williams for the valuable suggestions. I just started reading the details about scaling Tridion 2013 SP1 to manage the load and improve the performance of the overall system. I will be back with additional set of questions soon I start implementing it.